# emacs-rails vs rinari?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, emacs, rinari

I'm just coming back to rails coding after a long hiatus. I was using rinari previously but noticed that there's a new version of emacs-rails. Is anyone using either? Any preferences for one over the other? What are people using for their rails projects within emacs these days?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Rails On Emacs Group](http://groups.google.com/group/emacs-on-rails) sees little mention of emacs-rails, but many members are actively using rinari, often (but not always) in conjunction with nXhtml. Having switched from the first version of emacs-rails to rinari, I've been satisfied with its less invasive/totalitarian philosophy. I'm one of the two current rinari committers, and while the development isn't currently very active, one of the list members is working on [compatibility with Rails 3](http://github.com/rejeep/rinari).

**Update**: rinari works fine with Rails 3, I still use & maintain it myself.

Comment: I was using rinari but found that when editing html.erb with nxhtml, performance would crash something chronic...sometimes taking up to 30 seconds to type a character.  so I've gone with both for now.  Rinari for everything but html editing, which kinda blows because nxhtml is definitely very nice

Comment: Aha. I don't use nxhtml personally. Instead, I use a modified version of nxml-mode, with mmm-mode. (http://github.com/purcell/emacs.d)

However, if you post your config + versions etc. on the google group mentioned above, you'll most likely get a helpful response from Lennart, the nxhtml maintainer.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version of Rinari from github, but it's broken. First of all, it's missing required files. To try to fix the first problem I encountered, I had to download  separately the file `inf-ruby.el`. Now, when opening Emacs with `(require 'rinari)` in my `~/.emacs` file, Emacs complains: `File error: Cannot open load file, jump`.  It seems I should download yet more code separately. Even if I did manage to get Rinari to download, it looks like the functions would be broken: [https://github.com/eschulte/rinari/issues/41]. Needs to try harder.

Comment: Before you start complaining, you could at least make sure you read and follow the installation instructions: http://rinari.rubyforge.org/Basic-Setup.html#Basic-Setup -- you missed the submodule step. Better yet, install from the packages in Marmalade or Melpa. Also, the presence of a small and specific bug in the latest code does not render the package unusable. Please be more constructive and considerate.

Comment: Begging your pardon, but I did follow the instructions. They give two alternatives: downloading the latest code from Github, or cloning the project from the command line. The note mentions that the `git submodule` commands, which apparently fix some of the problems, have to be done in the **latter** case. Using the former method results in an installation that requires extra effort to get working. Given that there's also an error report that concerns the version of Emacs I'm using, I decided not to waste any more of my time on this tool. It might well be great, but everyone's time is limited.

Comment: Aha, sorry - I see what you mean, and apologise for my previous tone. The "download tarball" method would never have worked well; I've recently had Eric give me access to the rubyforge account, because the (very old) docs there need overhauling, and I'm the sole current maintainer of the code. I'm sorry that you had a disappointing experience; installing the ELPA packages is by far the most reliable method, if you ever want to try again.

Comment: BTW, the issue you were concerned about is now fixed.

Comment: OK, good, thanks for letting me know. I'll give rinari another whirl sometime soon. But please remember to add the missing code (`inf-ruby.el`, the `init` stuff, the `update` stuff) to both the tarball on Github and to the version downloadable through Emacs's package management system, so that it'll work out of the box.

Comment: The tarball is built automatically from source by Github, so I can't influence its contents -- github don't seem to include the submodule contents. `inf-ruby.el` is a declared dependency of the `rinari` package, so it will at least be automatically installed when installing `rinari` from Marmalade or Melpa.

Comment: Aha, get Steve Purcell out of Github

Answer (score 4):

I personally favor rinari. It has a smaller feature set, but it interacts nicely with other modes such as (nxhtml) and it doesn't get in your way. It's also available in ELPA. I'm not sure what new emacs-rails release are you referring to since there has been no activity in its [github repo](http://github.com/dima-exe/emacs-rails-reloaded) for over an year now. Rinari is still actively developed.